# Is there a general linear group version of general relativity (not diffeomorphism)?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, diffeomorphism, general-linear-group

General relativity is strongly based on the concept of diffeomorphism.

However diffeomorphisms are not linear.

I wish to recover as much of general relativity as possible, but while remain linear.

I understand that there are generalizations of gravity (metric-affine for instance), but here I am interested in a reduction to the general linear group.

Can I formulate a theory (hopefully as close to the original as possible) of gravity based on the general linear group, instead of diffeomorphism.

Comment: Wasn't the history sort of the other way around? There was a nice linear history, namely special relativity. Its generalization, namely general relativity, introduced curvature which introduce gravity.

Comment: @LeeMosher A reduction from Diffeomorphism to General linear invariance = special relativity???

Comment: @Anon21: Nobody says so. What Lee is explaining is that the natural group of "coordinate changes" in special relativity is the Poincare group (the semidirect product of the Lorentz group and the group of translations). The same will apply for flat Lorentzian manifolds. In contrast, in general relativity, since one deals with general semi-Riemannian metrics, the natural (pseudo)group of "coordinate changes" consists of general diffeomorphisms.

Comment: If you want a geometry whose group of coordinate changes consists of all affine transformations, then you are looking at "flat affine structures." I very much doubt that these have any relevance to physics.